# Water valve in basement connected to floor drain

Tags: plumbing

I have a line with a valve that is connected to the floor drain in basement. Is this supposed to run slowly or just be turned on occasionally to prevent smell?  I just discovered it is connected to the hot water line. Plumber said keep it off.  Turn on sometimes.  Should it be rerouted to the cold line?  Plumber installed this about four years ago.  I think at times it was on slowly and therefore wasting hot water. think he doesn’t want to confess to doing it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

I would add some cooking oil to the floor drain. This will prevent the water in the trap from evaporating. You'll no longer have to add water every other month or so. In fact, this may last a year or more. It did for me.